# Jquery event handling when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

*edit* Updated full code :

I'm working on my first Javascript case i'm stuck here :

I have the following :

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 {
  $('input, select').on('focus' ,swapPersonClass);

  //Blur = Bind an event handler to the “blur” JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.
 
  $('input, select').on("change", updateCart);
 }
);


// Functions
var swapPersonClass = function()
{
 var expression = $(this).attr('id');
 switch(expression) 
  {
   case "fullname":
    break;
   case "email":
    $("#arm").removeClass().addClass("pointemail");
    break;
   case "countpizzas":
    $("#arm").removeClass().addClass("pointamount");
    break;
   default:
    $("#arm").removeClass().addClass("pointothers");
  }
};

var updateCart = function () {
 var change = $(this).attr('id');
 console.log(change);
 
 $('input, select').each(function () 
 {
  switch (change) 
  {
   case "fullname":
    $("#displayname").text($('#fullname').val() + ',');
    break;
   
   case "countpizzas":
    aantalpizzas = $("#countpizzas").val();
    if (aantalpizzas > 1) {
     $('.plural').show();
    } else {
     $('.plural').hide();
    };
    $("#displayamount").text(aantalpizzas);
    console.log(aantalpizzas);
    break;
    
   case "pizzatype":
    PrijsPizza = $("#pizzatype option:selected").data("price");
    console.log(PrijsPizza);
    break;
      
   case "YesOption":
    $("#toppings").show();
    break;
    
   case "NoOption":
    $("#toppings").hide();
    break;
    
   case "toppings":
    updateTopping();
    break;
  };
  
   $("#currenttotal").text(aantalpizzas * PrijsPizza );
 });
};


var updateTopping = function () 
{
 $(".chk_topping").change(function()
 {
  var selected_topping = $(this).attr('data-value');
   switch(selected_topping)
   {
   case "salami":
    $("#currenttotal").text(aantalpizzas * PrijsPizza );
    PrijsTopping += 0.30;
    break
   }

 });
};

var PrijsTopping = 0.30;
var aantalpizzas = 0;
var PrijsPizza = 0;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Forms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/screen.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>


</head>
<body>
 <div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Pizza Palace</h1>

    </header>
    <aside>
        <h2><span>Order details</span></h2>

        <div id="total">
            <p>Your current order total: &euro; <strong id="currenttotal">0</strong></p>
        </div>

        <p><strong id="displayname"></strong> you are ordering <strong id="displayamount"></strong> pizza<span
                class="plural">s</span></p>

        <h3>Chosen toppings:</h3>
        
        <div id="toppingmessage">
            <p>No toppings selected</p>
            <ul>
                <li class="hide">Salami</li>
                <li class="hide">Olives</li>
                <li class="hide">Ansjovis</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Your discount: </h3>

        <p id="displaydiscount"></p>

    </aside>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <figure id="arm"></figure>
    <figure id="face"></figure>
    <fieldset class="personbody">

    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="fullname">Full Name
            <input id="fullname" name="fullnames" type="text" required autofocus> 
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter Your email" required>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
           <label for="howmany">How many pizzas would you like?<br><br>
            <input id="countpizzas" name="countpizzas" type="number" min="1" max="3" step="1" value="0" required>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div> 

        <label for="pizzatype">Which type of pizza would you like ? <br>
                <select id="pizzatype"name="pizzatype"> 
                    <option data-price="4" value="S">Small</option>
                    <option data-price="5.5" value="M">Medium</option>
                    <option data-price="7" value="L">Large</option>
                </select>
  </label> 
  </div>
        <div>
            <label for="extratopping">Would you like extra topping? <br>
                <input id="YesOption" name="ExtraTopping" type="radio"> Yes 
    <input id="NoOption" name="ExtraTopping" type="radio"> No
         </label>   
        </div>
        
        <div class="hide" id="toppings">
          <label for="toppings">Which toppings would you like?</label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="chk_topping" data-value="salami"> Salami
              <input type="checkbox" class="chk_topping" data-value="olives"> Olives 
              <input type="checkbox" class="chk_topping" data-value="ansjovis"> Ansjovis
        </div>
        <div> 
            <label for="deliverydate">When do you want the pizza<span class="plural">s</span> to be delivered?
             <input id="delivery" name="delivery" type="date" required > </label>
            <label for="deliverytime">
             <input id="Time" name="Time" type="time" required>   </label>
        </div>
            <label for="discountcode">Do you have a discount code?
            <input id="DiscountCode" name="DiscountCode" type="text" pattern="[1-9]{1}-[A-Z]{3}" title="The discount code should be a digit followed by a dash and then 3 uppercase letters" required> 
            </label> 
        </div>
    </form>
        <input type="submit" value="Place your order" name="placeorder"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>

    <footer><p>Graphics courtesy of &copy; Basecamp </p></footer>
</div>

 <script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='assets/js/script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Why my checkboxes keep telling me it's undefined when selecting them ? 
I'm realy not good at javascript so my code will probably be sh*t

Comment: Your code seems to be working if the `case` part and `updateTopping()` function is removed. What is the problem really?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/fcs8c362/. You will probably need to debug yours line by line to see where the exception is.  The only other thing is that the elements are not loaded into the DOM but this would depend on what other code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
    `var selected_topping = $(this).data('value');`

http://jsfiddle.net/f4Lghy6p/

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
 {
  $('input, select').on("change", updateCart);
 }
);

In my Updatecart function I have my Switch 
and in my case of my switch I have a new function UpdateTopping

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

i'm searching for a specefic ID in my select en input fields  :
        $('input, select').on("change", updateCart);

My checkboxes are located in a DIV with an input fields which don't have an ID.